# C# LoadLibrary from byte[]

Tags: c#, pinvoke, loadlibrary

I'd like to call LoadLibrary() to load a native DLL from an embedded resource.  I know how to get the byte[] for the embedded resource, but I do not know how to call LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() for a byte[]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666799/embedding-unmanaged-dll-into-a-managed-c-sharp-dll

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557293/is-it-possible-to-write-a-jit-compiler-to-native-code-entirely-in-a-managed-n

Answer (score 1):

You could look at this tutorial, but as has been previously stated, this is not trivial:

http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/

Answer (score 0):

Loading a library from memory is no easy task, and cannot be done with LoadLibray.

Why not save the native DLL to a temporary file and load it from there? You can delete when finished with it or when exiting your application.

Comment: I have a deployment restriction and am not able to write to disk